# How to prove the commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem that is to prove is,

> Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group and suppose $a \in G$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $2$ and is the unique such element. Show that $a \circ x=x \circ a$ for all $x \in G$.

I can't proceed at all however I have noted that (I don't know whether it is important but looks to me to have some connection to the complete solution) $\left(x \circ a \circ x^{-1}\right)\circ \left(x \circ a \circ x^{-1}\right)=e$ but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there! You have shown that $xax^{-1}$ also has order dividing 2. You need to show that it can't be $e$, and then you'll have that $xax^{-1}$ has order 2. But by hypothesis $a$ was the unique element of order 2... what does that tell us?

Comment: It's that trivial! Oh my!